# DataGridView save filtering after reload

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview, filtering

I have some problem with DataGridView in C#.

case is:

I do some update on database then I reload DataGridView with new values:

```
myDataGridView.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables[0]
```

Everything is ok, but recently I was asked if there is possibility to keep the same column filtering applied after reloading data?

What would be approach to do this filtering case?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution, maybe it will help somebody:
[btw. I made some language mistake filtering = sorting ;-)]

```
   DataGridViewColumn oldColumn = dataGridView1.SortedColumn;

   ListSortDirection direction;
   if (dataGridView1.SortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending) direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
   else direction = ListSortDirection.Descending;

   databaseUpdateFunction();

   DataGridViewColumn newColumn = dataGridView1.Columns[oldColumn.Name.ToString()];
   dataGridView1.Sort(newColumn,direction);
   newColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection =
                    direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending ?
                    SortOrder.Ascending : SortOrder.Descending;
```

I used parts of code from : [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171608.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

I took kuba's solution, and put it in a utility class I can use on any `DataGridView`:

```
    private static ListSortDirection _oldSortOrder;
    private static DataGridViewColumn _oldSortCol;

    /// <summary>
    /// Saves information about sorting column, to be restored later by calling RestoreSorting
    /// on the same DataGridView
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="grid"></param>
    public static void SaveSorting(DataGridView grid)
    {
        _oldSortOrder = grid.SortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending ?
            ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;
        _oldSortCol = grid.SortedColumn;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Restores column sorting to a datagrid. You MUST call this AFTER calling 
    /// SaveSorting on the same DataGridView
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="grid"></param>
    public static void RestoreSorting(DataGridView grid)
    {
        if (_oldSortCol != null)
        {
            DataGridViewColumn newCol = grid.Columns[_oldSortCol.Name];
            grid.Sort(newCol, _oldSortOrder);
        }
    }
```

Using this looks like:

```
GridUtility.SaveSorting(grid);    
grid.DataSource = databaseFetch(); // or whatever
GridUtility.RestoreSorting(grid);
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across Adam Nofsinger's answer before I encounterd the problem, but I used it anyway. It works wonderfull.

Just needed to add these 2 **using** lines to my class file:

```
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Thanks,
Geert.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    //preserve existing sort column and direction
    ListSortDirection direction;
    DataGridViewColumn oldsort = MyDataGridView.SortedColumn;
    if (MyDataGridView.SortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
    {   direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending; } else { direction = ListSortDirection.Descending; }

    //this is refresh
    MyDataGridView.DataSource = data;

    //reapply sort and direction
    if (oldsort != null) { MyDataGridView.Sort(MyDataGridView.Columns[oldsort.Name], direction); }
```