# C# winforms gridview sorting after binding data programatically

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, datagridview, gridview-sorting

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadermouseclick(v=vs.110).aspx

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(
    object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    // Sort the selected column.
    dataGridView1.Sort(newColumn, direction);
    newColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection =
        direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending ?
        SortOrder.Ascending : SortOrder.Descending;
}

public CustomersListWrapper(DataGridView gridView)
{
    _gridView = gridView;
    _gridView.CellClick += dgwCustomersList_CellContentClick;
    _gridView.ColumnHeaderMouseClick += dgwCustomersList_ColumnHeaderMouseClick;

    ClearGrid();
    SetCustomersListHeader();
    ....

}

private void ClearGrid()
{
    _gridView.Rows.Clear();
    _gridView.Columns.Clear();
}

private void SetCustomersListHeader()
{
    _gridView.Columns.Add(DataGridViewColumnNames.Customers.ID, "Id");
    _gridView.Columns.Add(DataGridViewColumnNames.Customers.NAME, "Ime");
    _gridView.Columns[1].Width = 360;
    _gridView.Columns.Add(DataGridViewColumnNames.Customers.SURNAME, "Priimek");
    _gridView.Columns[2].Width = 360;
    _gridView.Columns.Add(DataGridViewColumnNames.Customers.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, "Št. računa");
    _gridView.Columns[3].Width = 120;
    _gridView.Columns.Add(DataGridViewColumnNames.Customers.CUSTOMER_NUMBER, "Št. stranke");
    _gridView.Columns[4].Width = 120;

    int nLastColumn = _gridView.Columns.Count - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < _gridView.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        if (nLastColumn == i)
        {
            _gridView.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

but the problem is that sorting is not working it is always Ascending. I am binding every time new data to the grid dynamically and looks like this reset the grid sorting,

```
newColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection
```

has correct value but after binding data data is lost and `SortGlyphDirection` is None again.

can I somehow remember value of the Column of the gridview after binding?

Comment: check whether the answer for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475807/datagridview-save-filtering-after-reload) question helps

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are binding data source from DataTable right? Changing data source resets previous sorting, I think there is more ways how handle this issue:
 - store last used sorting order in variable and use DataGridView.DataSourceChanged or DataGridView.DataBindingComplete events to sort your new data source and refresh grid
 - store last used sorting order and before attaching new data source sort your source DataTable to sorting order used in DataGridView and change datasource after this

Answer (score 0):

You must inherit IBindingList on your datasource. On Databind.

Loop and bind this way Instead, is easier in my opinion.

```
        dg_Transactions.Columns.Add("1", "Date");
        dg_Transactions.Columns.Add("2", "Amount");
        dg_Transactions.Columns.Add("3", "Description");

        foreach (var row in data.Transactions)
        {
            var n = dg_Transactions.Rows.Add();

            var i = 0;
            dg_Transactions.Rows[n].Cells[i++].Value = row.Date;;
            dg_Transactions.Rows[n].Cells[i++].Value = row.Amount;
            dg_Transactions.Rows[n].Cells[i++].Value = row.Description;
        }
```